# Angular Get queryParam from URL when no name is specified

Tags: angular

How do you get query information from a URL like this:

`http://localhost:4200/reset?c564e265451e2e24be460f30271678b566d20fa9962000063bb6d079f5e376a0=`

If it was `http://...reset?token=c56...` I can grab the value using `queryParams` by doing something like:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params)=>this.token = params['token']);`
```

but I can't figure out how to get the token when  the query parameter has no name.  I can see the value under _value when logging `this.route.queryParams` to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a couple solutions:

The first solution I found seemed a bit ugly:

```
this.route.queryParams.forEach((value) => this.token = Object.keys(value).shift());
```

Then I found `queryParamMap`, which made it less ugly:

```
this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe((value) => this.token = value.keys.shift());
```

So I've used the `queryParamMap` solution unless someone can find a short hand way of doing the same thing.