# Expression expected when trying to access query params in Angular 2

Tags: angular2-routing

I tried to access query params using below code.

```
let name : string = this.route.snapshot?.queryParams.name
        console.log(name);
```

And I got the below error:

```
error TS1109: Expression expected

error TS1005: ':' expected

does not exist on type 'Params'.
```

How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem lies in the way you treat `queryParams`.
It returns observable so you can change your code like that:

```
let name: string = '';
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(res => {
                          name = res.ResponseNameProperty;
                          console.log(name);                           
                       });
```

The `res.ResponseNameProperty` is way how you get the `name` property from revived object so you can first check how it looks using i.e. `console.log(res)` and than use appropriate reference. I hope it fits your question and here you can found additional information about observables:
[thoughtram](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html)
, [official page](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#first-examples), [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056847/angular-get-queryparam-from-url-when-no-name-is-specified)